# Passing values to next page using anchor tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, post, anchor

One quick question -

I have an anchor tag which on clicking opens a new target window.

I don't want to pass the values either in post or get method.

my html code is like this.

```
    <a class="employee_details" target="_blank" href="index1.php?name=username&id=123">UserName</a>
```

Is there a way to pass the values to the next page using jquery in a hidden type since there is no submit button.
In other words, clicking the anchor tag will redirect to another one page where i should get the name and id and that part should NOT BE VISIBLE ANYWHERE in the url.

Any help
Kimz

Comment: Maybe you can store it in cookies if you don't want it in url?

Comment: Anything stored in javasript/jquery is visible to the end user. Are you trying to hide it from the user or make it more `presentable`?

Comment: you can do it using Session and also by cookies

Comment: the value and employee name must not be visible for the users in the browser part. but the employee name and id can be visible in the next page (i.e - index1.php)

Comment: `$_POST` is not visible in the url

Comment: as @f00644 asked, are you hiding it for *security* reason or *presentation* reason?

Answer (score 2):

You said that you don't want anything in the url to be shown except from page name so why not using a form with psot method? Post will not show anything in the browser and you won't have to deal with sessions/cookies which require more work.

From documentation

> - POST requests are never cached
> - POST requests do not remain in the browser history
> - POST requests cannot be bookmarked
> - POST requests have no restrictions on data length

```
<form method="post" action="index1.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="username" />
  <input type="hidden" name="username" value="123" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
</form>
```

Now in your second page you just need to retrieve data you need throw variable `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['username']`. You can also make your submit button look like a link with some css.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **session variable** to pass the value from one page to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this includes a href tag and onclick does call javascript function.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action ="b.php" id="testform" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="username" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="123" />
</form>
<a class="employee_details" onclick="test()">UserName</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test()
{
document.forms.testform.submit();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should keep the `anchor` outside of the `form` in this case to preserve `inline-display`..

Comment: inline-display means?

Comment: `Form` is a `display:block` element which will force the other elements around the anchor to not share the line it sits on..... e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_display&preval=block